# What's the recommended way to raise a possible proof as a question?

Tags: discussion

I am a self-taught math amateur who came to this site primarily to learn.  It is a great place for asking any mathematical question!  The site has provided me with an unprecedented ability to gain understanding on what would otherwise be esoteric topics (gamma function, log-convex functions, Stirling approximation, Ramanujan's proof of Betrand's postulate, Jitsuro Nagura's classic 1952 proof, etc.)  Thank you very much for this great learning experience!  :-)

As a result of all these tips and hints, I've started coming up with what might be elementary mathematical proofs.  I assumed that I was making some mistake somewhere and asked the question such as "Where is my mistake..." or "Is this valid...".

Interestingly, all 3 of my proposed proofs have gotten upvotes (8 upvotes for the [first](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353566/understanding-ramanujans-approach-in-his-proof-of-bertrands-postulate), 15 upvotes for the [second](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356912/generalizing-ramanujans-proof-of-bertrands-postulate-can-ramanujans-approach), and 5 upvotes for a [third](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360343/is-it-possible-to-generalize-ramanujans-lower-bound-for-factorials-that-he-used)).  Unfortunately, I didn't get any answers such as "this is well known" or "you have a gap in step 2" or "it might be worth developing more".  I am wondering on the best way to proceed to get this type of feedback.

Should I at this point create a bounty for the question?  Should I pose the question on a different site?  Would it be appropriate for me to ask a more directed question to the site such as "Is there anything here that might merit consideration for being posted on arxiv.org?"

Thanks very much,

-Larry

---

**Update:** I have received comments on the [third attempted proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360343/is-it-possible-to-generalize-ramanujans-lower-bound-for-factorials-that-he-used).  Mistakes were found which invalidate the argument.

Comment: Could you please link to the 3 proposed proofs.

Comment: Bounties are the usual way of getting more eyes.

Comment: Thanks for the request, Math Gems!  I've added the links to the three proposed elementary proofs.

Comment: Thanks, @Aryabhata, I've started a bounty of $50$ for [one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356912/generalizing-ramanujans-proof-of-bertrands-postulate-can-ramanujans-approach) of my questions.  Cheers.

Comment: Do you have a brother called [Gordon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon_Freeman)?

Comment: No.  My only brother is named Scott.

Comment: I believe it is not necessary to adjust the numbers each time you receive an upvote, comment or answer. It should go without saying that these numbers are bound to change, and were correct at the time of writing.

Comment: Sorry.  I'll stop doing that.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597/best-way-of-asking-check-my-proof-questions/5026#5026

Comment: Thanks, Michael.  I appreciate the answer.  I realize that it's dangerous to ask for review of a proof so I tried to keep my argument short and my logical steps clear.  My hope is that even when mistakes are found, my question is still of interest to ambitious undergraduates or early graduate students.